# Specs on an AC-DC adapter that has two outputs

Tags: adapter

I have a custom adapter with 2 outputs that are the same in each output.  Based on the below specs what are the outputs of each of the cables coming from my adapter?

- Input: 100-120V~3A
- Output:12V-12.5A
- Positive polarity

And I know the output in each is 75w.  So what is it?

- 6V and 12.5A

or

- 12v and 6.25A

Oh and this powers an external Graphics card for a laptop.  One plug is for the Graphics card the other is for the housing device. I already tried looking up the input specs for the card with no luck.

Comment: If its not labeled, break out a multimeter.

Comment: So measure them, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the two outputs are both +12V, and the total available current from both outputs is 12.5A. We really can't be 100% sure though.